# What does PACK8/16/32 mean in VkFormat names?

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to understand the names of the items in the `VkFormat` enum, and so far I think I get all the structure of the names of all of the (non-block) formats, but I can't figure out what it means when they have a suffix of `PACK8`, `PACK16`, `PACK32`. If I add up the channel sizes, they always add up to 8, 16, or 32, nothing irregular, so I don't understand what it would mean to bit-pack these values, since they seem to be 100% efficient, using all their bits.

As usual, [the documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/xhtml/vkspec.html#features-formats-definition) is not very helpful, just saying the format is packed without saying what that means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PACK fields mean exactly what the specification says they mean:

> whole texels or attributes are stored in a single data element, rather than individual components occupying a single data element

Though if you find that too confusing, you could just look at the actual format descriptions. Vulkan goes into excruciating detail about them, to the point of needless repetition.

The difference between `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_RGB` and `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_RGB_PACK32` is the same difference between a `uint8_t[4]` and a `uint32_t`. One is an array ("individual components"), while the other is a single value ("single data element") made up of smaller values.

If you have a `uint8_t color[4]` array, which stores `B8G8R8A8`, then `color[0]` stores the blue component. The order of the components in the array is defined by the order of the components in the format's name.

If you have a `uint32_t color` value, which stores `B8G8R8A8`, then `(color & 0xFF000000) >> 24` will retrieve the blue component. The highest byte is the first, followed by the next highest and so forth.

The reason the packed-vs-not-packed distinction matters is because of [endian issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Arrays of bytes don't have endian issues. But values packed into 16 or 32-bits do have endian issues. The endian of the packed formats is always assumed to be the native endian of the host.

Comment: Hi @NicolBolas, would you mind explaining something or perhaps extending the answer? You explain the technical difference of `uint_8[4]` and `uint32_t`, but it still doesn't say why I should care. Should I check the endianness of my machine/my GPU (maybe have a macro check), and then based on that pick any of the two options? Ie. how to take the knowledge obtained here and translate it into program logic. Thanks.

Comment: @alexpanter: Broadly speaking, most images come from files, and the data in those files have the format that they have. So as far as your Vulkan-interfacing code is concerned, you only need to do two things: identify what Vulkan format the image is, and possibly alter the image's bytes to conform to a format the implementation supports.